# Loading different EDGE compositions dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-edge

I'm trying to build a test-system for edge-animate composition, so I can load different compositions and test if they display correctly, change their customizable fields and so on. I tried the Edge Commons' EC.loadComposition function, but I have a problem with passing the composition-name from the outer html.
I've got the Main Composition that contains the field, where the external comps will be loaded. I managed to run the "Composition Loader" example (http://edgedocks.com/content/2013/12/nesting-animate-compositions-composition-loader-edge-commons), but I would love to give the user a chance to name a composition to load, from browser-level.

I guess it's going to have somthing in common with Bootstrapping the Compositions, but I'm fairly new to html/JS/Edge and I can't make it work as I want to.

Do you know any solutions, or directions to look at?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround:

In the Bootstrap callback, I call AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindElementAction() and then bind a loading function to a symbol, that works as a button. With this approach, I can use JS or PHP to fill the composition-name argument of that function.

My Code is totally cramped, because I copied it from the edge-generated .js file, but it looks like this:

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
    comp = AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId);
    AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, 'stage', "${Button1}", "click", function(sym,e){
var loadedComp=EC.loadComposition(document.getElementById('idCard').value ,sym.$("Content"));loadedComp.done(function(comp)
{ loadedStage=comp.getStage();});});});
```

Sorry for the mess, but it contains so much nested definitions that I'm unable to format it to look good ;(

If you find any better way to solve this, let me know!